# How can I identify this element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to identify this element "Question With Text Response" which has no unique id, class or attribute.

I have tried this:

```
@FindBy(css = "body")
```

Can anyone please help me to locate this?

Here is the HTML:

```html
<tr valign="top" xpath="1">
   <td width="80%">
      <div id="div-4fd242f670a4bc4e0170beb543d72c66" class="wordwrap" style="padding-left:20px;padding-top:3px;">
         <label for="name" class="portlet-form-field-label">
         2.
         Question With Text Response<span style="color:red;">*</span>
         </label>
         <br>
         <textarea id="4fd242f670a4bc4e0170beb543d72c66" name="answers[4fd242f670a4bc4e0170beb543d72c66]" class="portlet-form-input-field answers[4fd242f670a4bc4e0170beb543d72c66]  comment" style="width:90%;" onkeydown="return imposeMaxLength(event, this, 3999);" onblur="return imposeMaxLength(event, this, 3999);" rows="7"></textarea>        
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your HTML structure the `label` and `textarea` are sibling tags So to locate textarea based on label text,

Use below xpath:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//label[contains(.,'Question With Text Response')]/following::textarea")
```

**Explanation:**

`//label[contains(.,'Question With Text Response')]`  - find label which contains text 'Question With Text Response'

`/following::textarea` or `/following-sibling::textarea` - locate the text are which follows the label

Comment: Do you want this text `Question With Text Response` to print ? or want to enter some text in textarea which has this label

Comment: "label[for='name'][class='portlet-form-field-label']" 
I have tried this but it is not unique I have two element for same in html

Comment: I want to enter in text area

Comment: @sap, Updated answer please check and let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can find the element using its text in the xpath.
You can do it like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Question With Text Response')]"));
```

Comment: @sap can you check if there is any iframe present on the page by checking its html